# Project Not Loading in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I recently installed the Windows Phone 7 SDK that came bundled with Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. I downloaded a sample app and tried to open the solution file. When I checked the solution view window, the app project was not loaded. Every time I tried to reload the project, it flash as available for a moment and then go back to being unavailable. I tried all the usual tricks like removing source control from the .csproj and deleting the .user and .suo files. Any ideas?

Comment: if you see unloaded project . then go edit .csproj file by right click and remove files which are not there in solution

Comment: There is only one project and there are no files that aren't needed.

Comment: no i mean your downloaded project has .cs files and other folders etc.. see in .csproj whether it is there or not..

Comment: They do all seem to be there in the .csproj.

Comment: any thing else which is there in .csproj file list but not in solution

Comment: No. There's only a path to Silverlight but I have it installed and the path is correct.

Comment: Actually even if they were some missing file, it will not prevent the solution to load. Did you look at the console to see if there is any error message? Did you try to click right and select ReloadProject, maybe the project has been unloaded from the solution.

Comment: I keep trying to reload, it then flashes as available and is then unloaded again. The output shows no error, just "Loaded Project So&So.csproj" and then the next line is "Unloaded Project So&So.csproj".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. When I open the solution file, it opens in Visual Studio 2010 Shell. What I needed to do was to go to Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone, open existing project, and then browse to the solution file and open it. Sorry for the confusion everyone!